# How to validate the JSON Path using jayway/jsonpath?

Tags: java, jsonpath

My JSON path looks like,

`$.broker.potentialAction[?(@.object.name=='Groupon' && @.object.@type=='Organization')]`

I tried validating it with

`new JsonContext().parse("{}").read("$.broker.potentialAction[?(@.object.name=='NGO' && @.object.@type=='Organization')]")`

However, it throws the JSON path exception even though the path is a valid one.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I was getting JsonPathException even though it was a valid JSON path string. However, i think i've fixed it below. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to do it,

```
JsonPath.compile(""$.broker.potentialAction[?(@.object.name=='NGO' && @.object.@type=='Organization')]"");
```